# AJAX won't submit data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am just learning AJAX. Our assignment this week was submitting a form with Ajax. However I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, as it won't submit.

The PHP works on its own. And it needs to be available as a backup option in case JavaScript is disabled.

```
<?php

    $final_content='';

if( isset($_POST["u_name"]) && isset($_POST["u_lastname"]) && isset($_POST["u_email"]) ){

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (Name, Lastname, Email)

    VALUES ('".$_POST["u_name"]."','".$_POST["u_lastname"]."','".$_POST["u_email"]."')";


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."";
    }

    $conn->close();


}else {
    $final_content = '<form action="script.php" method="post" id="user_form">

    <input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Name" id="user_name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="u_lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="user_lastname"> <br>
    <input type="email" name="u_email" placeholder="Email" id="user_email"> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>';
}
?>

<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //Set form variable
            var form = $("#user_form");

            form.submit(function(event){

                //Set data variables
                var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
                var user_lastname = $("#user_lastname").val();
                var user_email = $("#user_email").val();

                    //Check if values are set
                    if( ($.trim(user_name) != "") && ($.trim(user_lastname) != "") && ($.trim(user_email) != "") ){

                        $.post("script.php", {u_name: user_name}, {u_lastname: user_lastname}, {u_email: user_email}, function(data){

                            $("#results").html(data);   

                        });
                    }

                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>



<div id="results"></div>

<?php echo $final_content ?>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Your data is supposed to be a single object, not several passed as separate arguments.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Like this then `{u_name: user_name, u_lastname: user_lastname, u_email: user_email}`?

Comment: Yes, that would be a single object.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks. Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Eek, the above has SQL injection vulnerabilities in it - don't put this live.

Comment: @halfer I thought mysqli was supposed to be better at that? Or is it my fault?

Comment: MySQLi is indeed better than the deprecated MySQL extension, but you don't get protection against SQL injection without also switching to parameterisation. See the [mysqli section here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) or search for "PHP mysqli parameterisation" on the web.

Comment: @halfer I'd love to improve my MySQL, but I think that link is too advanced for me :(

Comment: What, all three lines of it? `:-)`. Just [read the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Personally I prefer PDO, but if you are already using MySQLi, stick with it.

Comment: @halfer the second link is much more helpful...thank you. What about filtering the _POST. In here I'm not showing that, but i am processing the _post when it reaches my php to only allow text and remove everything for the name fields. And also process the email that way too. Does that help at all?

Comment: It is certainly possible to write a filtering routine that cleans `$_POST`, but what happens if you then want to write apostrophes in the database? If you have removed them then you'll need to add in rules to escape them in certain cases - it is really just easier to parameterise them when running the database operation.

Comment: @halfer Would this be an acceptable way of doing it `$clean_var = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($var);`?

Comment: Yes, that would certainly work. I prefer parameterisation since it is harder for security detection tools to determine if concatenated SQL strings have been correctly escaped, and it is easier with concatenation to accidentally use a user-tainted variable. However, if you find that easier then it's a good first step.

Comment: @halfer It's way easier for the moment...but I'll keep parameterization in mind. Thanks again. You're awesome, not many people in here are this helpful and patient. `:)`

Comment: No problem, and you are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $.post("script.php", {u_name: user_name}, {u_lastname: user_lastname}, {u_email: user_email}, function(data){
       $("#results").html(data);   
});
```

**Replace the above lines with following code :**

```
$.post("script.php", {u_name: user_name,u_lastname: user_lastname,u_email: user_email}, function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);   
});
```

and for more detail about different options with `$.post()` function you can refer to following link :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/